# Is there a way to draw directly onto a model/texture in threejs?

Tags: three.js, textures, raycasting

I've been looking for a solution to this problem for a project I'm working on. I'd like to know if there is a way to click on a plane geometry and draw onto it, paint style, and have the texture update as you draw on it.

After this, is there a way to save that texture while in the browser now that you've edited it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use raycasting to determine the UV texture position where the mouse intersection takes place. [`Raycaster.intersectObject`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Raycaster.intersectObject) returns an array of objects, one of its properties is `.uv`. You can see it in action in [this demo](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=raycast#webgl_raycast_texture).

You can use a 2D `<canvas>` as the source of the texture. Once you have the UVs from the intersection, you could use that position to draw on the canvas [as demonstrated in this other demo](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=canvas#webgl_materials_texture_canvas)

Comment: Just to add to the above, there is also the decal demo https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_decals.html

Comment: @2pha The only issue with that demo is that each decal creates a new mesh that renders on top of the head, so it wouldn't be editing the original texture.

Comment: Thanks Marquizzo, I tried something like this and it works

Comment: @Marquizzo, yeh, I was just linking to it as an extra example that may help. The second demo/example you linked to is actually my contribution to the three.js repository :)